# .NET + Angular Template API Controller Route not working (404)

Tags: c#, .net, routes, controller, .net-6.0

When I used This Template:

[Template](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YMDTl.png)

for an Angular Frontend .NET Backend. But when I created an API Controller like this in the Controller Directory:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;

namespace API.Controllers
{
    [Route("[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class TestController : ControllerBase
    {

        [HttpGet]
        public int Get()
        {
            return 0;
        }
    }
}
```

I always get 404 Not Found in Postman with query "https://localhost:44490/Test" even though the "WeatherForecastController" template that was already in the Project works fine.
I tried the TestController in another Template that is just  the .NET Backend and it works fine, I get a normal 200 back...

I also tried a 1 to 1 copy of the WeatherForecastController the Template came with but that also did not Work, I think the Program does not even get to the Controller so I guess there is something wrong with the routing setup. Im new to .Net so I might just have overseen something.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

This is the Program.cs that came with the Project:

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.

builder.Services.AddControllers();

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
    app.UseHsts();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();
app.UseRouting();


app.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "default",
    pattern: "{controller}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

app.MapFallbackToFile("index.html");

app.Run();
```

Comment: What is the work project using for the Target Net/Core.?  I suspect the template is targeting a different version of Net/Core.

Comment: @jdweng Visual Studio says the Target Framework is .NET 6.0, how do I find out what the template is targeting?

Comment: Open the template and check in the project settings.  The csproj file is text and can be opened with notepad.

Comment: @jdweng the csproj file also says the target framework is net6.0...

Comment: So I do not think it has to do with version of Net/Core.  Were you running both projects from inside VS or using the exe file?  When you are inside VS you are not an ADMIN unless you right click the VS shortcut and select Run As Admin.  Are you on same machine when testing both apps?

Comment: Try removing the app.MapControllerRoute() and add app.MapControllers()